# totally command line(CLI) linux os

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, command-line-interface

Is there any OS such satisfies the title?
I want to use Command Line Interface, not GUI, because I want it.
I want to be friendly with Command Line Interface.

Comment: as far as i know all linux distros support this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GUI is not part of the Linux kernel, in opposition to Windows. That means you can safely remove the graphical part (X server and dependencies) from any Linux distribution, and end up with a simple terminal. Some distributions (e.g. Ubuntu) propose an alternative minimal install without GUI, and others (e.g. Arch Linux) just don't include it.

Note however that if your purpose is really (as you mention) to get friendly with CLI, the GUI layer can also be your friend. It allows you to compose your main display with many virtual terminals, which can be helpful to contemplate process command interactions. Internet is also a powerful way to learn about shell syntax and behavior, and a non-graphical browser can be a real pain to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! GUI is not included in Linux kernel, ah-ha!

Answer (score 3):

Just use any Linux distro you like and go to *console mode*.

There are six consoles available. Each one is accessible with the shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>.

If and when you want to return to the GUI desktop again, you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: An upvote for you,but would you mind stating what are these six consoles about in brief!

Comment: @shekharsuman: The Linux console is explained very well in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console). The Linux console is a system console internal to the Linux kernel (a system console is the device which receives all kernel messages and warnings and which allows logins in single user mode). In modern Linux, you can think of those 6 consoles as "virtual" consoles (consoles that are logically separate, but which access the same physical keyboard and display) that you can use simultaneously.

Comment: If I'm not going to use a GUI why would I install an OS that includes one?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few useful resources.

Looking for a fast CLI Linux distro:
https://superuser.com/questions/275540/looking-for-a-fast-cli-linux-distro

minimal linux distro for USB (just CLI and command line tools):
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/minimal-linux-distro-for-usb-just-cli-and-command-line-tools-4175480576/

Tiny Core Linux:
http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/

INX Is Not X : A command line and console Linux "Live CD" based on a minimal Ubuntu
http://inx.maincontent.net/

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, GUI is on top of Linux kernel and can be easily switched off. Linux can be started with the different [run levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel), so all you need is take your favourite distribution and change the default run level level to 2 (Multi-user Mode with Networking). For example, in Ubuntu (as of 12.04) this can be done by editing */etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf* file and setting *DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL* to 2:

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```